# How to attach a click handler for an anchor in a custom HTMLElement in java script?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, htmlelements

I am writing a HTMLElement and trying to add anchor tags to the html dynamically. I am able to add anchor tags to innerHtml (`createLink` function in my code), but onClick event handlers are missing. How can I attach onClick event handlers in javascript. I am writing my code in typescript and transpiling to js using babble and webpack.

```
export class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
constructor() {
    super();
}

private _serviceResponse: Employee[];

connectedCallback() {
    this.getData();
    this.innerHTML = '';
}

getData() {
    let fetch = window.fetch.bind(window);
    fetch('http://localhost/api/v1/values')
        .then(response => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((data: Employee[]) => {
            this._serviceResponse = data;
            console.log(this._serviceResponse);
            this.renderHtml();
        });
}

renderHtml() {
    this.innerHTML = `
            <table style="width: 100%;" border="2" >
                <thead>
                    <th>Header1</th>
                    <th>Header2</th>
                    <th>Header3</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    ${this._serviceResponse.map(employee => { return this.getEmployeeTemplate(employee); })}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            `;
}

getEmployeeTemplate(employee: Employee) {
    switch (employee.Type) {
        case "1":
            return this.getRegularTemplate(order);
        case "2":
            return `<tr><td colspan=3>Test Row}</td></tr>`;
    }
}

getRegularTemplate(emp: Employee): string {
    return `
    <tr>
        <td> ${emp.FirstName} </td>
        <td> ${emp.LastName} </td>
        <td>
            ${this.createLink(emp)}
        </td>
    </tr>
    `;
}

createLink(emp: Employee): string {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.innerHTML = 'Details';
    anchor.onclick = () =>  { this.handleDetailsClick(emp); };
    anchor.href = '#';
    return anchor.outerHTML;
}

handleDetailsClick(emp: Employee) {
    console.log('Details link clicked: ' + emp);
}

handleDetailsClick() {
    console.log('clicked');
}
```

}

When it renders on the UI, I see this anchor tag, but the onClick event handler is missing.

```
<a href="#">Details</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because Adding an event handler via `on<event>` property doesn't affect HTML attributes.

Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers#Details).

Answer (score 0):

### outerHTML

```
createLink(emp: Employee): string {
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.innerHTML = 'Details';
    anchor.onclick = () =>  { this.handleDetailsClick(emp); };
    anchor.href = '#';
    return anchor.outerHTML;
}
```

The `return anchor.outerHTML` statement serialises the anchor element using the [HTML fragment serialization algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#serializing-html-fragments) .  Step 3.2 of the algorithm's describes how it takes an elemenent's attributes (which have text values) and converts them into markup for the element.

This line:

```
 anchor.onclick = () =>  { this.handleDetailsClick(emp); };
```

does not create an attribute - it creates a function property ("method") attached to the anchor element. It is not processed by the serialization algorithm and doesn't survive being inserted into the custom element's `innerHTML` as part of a text string.

A quick test shows that even as text, the click handler must be explicitly added as an attribute to be serialized:

```js
"use strict";
var anchor = document.createElement('a');
anchor.innerHTML = 'Details';
anchor.onclick = "clickHandle()"
console.log("Setting a property doesn't work: " + anchor.outerHTML);
anchor.setAttribute("onclick", "clickHandle");
console.log("Setting an attribute does work: " + anchor.outerHTML);
```

### Potential Solutions

The design aim is to show employee details when a link is clicked. The restriction is that if the link must be internally handled as text, it's click handler would have to call a global click handler from within a code fragment - which would smell.

One alternative would be to delegate click handling to a single handler added to the custom element during construction, and add a data attribute to link elements containing an employee index used to access private class data (which can't be reached from HTML source code).

### Example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Custom Element</title>
<script>

class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.onclick = event => {
        let link = event.target;
        let index = +link.dataset.index;
        if( link.tagName === 'A' && index >= 0) {
            this.handleDetailsClick( this._serviceResponse[ index]);
        }
    };
    // FOR TESTING ONLY:
    function Employee( index) {
        this.FirstName = "Firstname" + index;
        this.LastName = "Lastname" + index;
        this.Type = "1";
    }
    this._serviceResponse = [ new Employee(1), new Employee(2)];
    setTimeout( this.renderHtml.bind(this), 10)
}
 
renderHtml() {
    this.innerHTML = `
            <table style="width: 100%;" border="2" >
                <thead>
                    <th>Header1</th>
                    <th>Header2</th>
                    <th>Header3</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    ${this._serviceResponse.map( this.getEmployeeTemplate.bind( this)).join(" ")}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            `;
  }

// ts: getEmployeeTemplate(employee: Employee, number: index ) {
// js:

getEmployeeTemplate( employee, index) {
    switch (employee.Type) {
        case "1":
            return this.getRegularTemplate(employee, index);
        case "2":
            return `<tr><td colspan=3>Test Row}</td></tr>`;
    }
}

// ts: getRegularTemplate(emp: Employee, number: index): string {
// js:

getRegularTemplate(emp, index){
    return `
    <tr>
        <td> ${emp.FirstName} </td>
        <td> ${emp.LastName} </td>
        <td>
            ${this.createLink(index)}
        </td>
    </tr>
    `;
  }

createLink(index){
    return `<a href="#" data-index="${index}">Details</a>`;
}

handleDetailsClick(emp) {
    console.log('Details link clicked: ', emp);
}
} // end of class

customElements.define('employee-s', MyCustomElement);
</script>

</head>
<body>

    <employee-s></employees>

</body>
</html>
```

Note the above snippet has

- commented out TypeScript so it can run here,
- test code added in the constructor,
- modified `renderHtml` to use `getEmployeeTemplate` as the map function,
- passed the second map parameter (i.e. the array index) to `createLink`,
- simplified `createLink`.

Also note that custom elements can't have child nodes when created from custom tags - the test code calls `renderHTML` asynchronously because of this.

Comment: I tried using setAttribute `anchor.setAttribute('onClick', 'handleDetailsClick');`. But on the browser, its not finding the function `Uncaught ReferenceError: handleDetailsClick is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick`

Comment: This is because attributes are text and for an event handler, treated as a source code snippet  and compiled by the HTML parser independently of the class definition - the compiled event handler has no access to class internals.